What can I do with model that always overfits?
I need to recognize 35 classes (9 numbers and 26 English letters). I have 700 images, example. I split it 80% - train, 20% - validation.
My model is very small:
import torch
from torch.nn import Module, Conv2d, MaxPool2d, ReLU, BatchNorm2d, BatchNorm1d, Linear, LeakyReLU, Softmax, AdaptiveMaxPool2d, Dropout

class CNNBlock(Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = Conv2d(
            in_channels = in_channels,
            out_channels = out_channels,
            kernel_size = 3,
            padding = "same"
        )
        self.batchnorm = BatchNorm2d(num_features = out_channels)
        self.act = ReLU()
        self.dropout = Dropout(0.8)
        self.maxpool = MaxPool2d(
            kernel_size = 2,
            stride = 2
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.maxpool(self.dropout(self.act(self.batchnorm(self.conv(x)))))

class RecognitionModel(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # Input 1x80x180
        self.block1 = CNNBlock(1, 32) # Block1 32x40x90
        self.block2 = CNNBlock(32, 64) # Block2 64x20x45
        self.gmp = AdaptiveMaxPool2d(output_size = 1) # GlobalMaxPool 64x1x1
        self.sqz = lambda x: x.squeeze() # Squeeze 64
        self.linear1 = Linear(
            in_features = 64,
            out_features = 32
        )
        self.batchnorm = BatchNorm1d(num_features = 32)
        self.act1 = LeakyReLU()
        self.dropout = Dropout(0.8)
        self.linear2 = Linear(
            in_features = 32,
            out_features = 35
        )
        self.act2 = Softmax(dim = 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.block1(x)
        x = self.block2(x)
        x = self.gmp(x)
        x = self.sqz(x)
        x = self.dropout(self.act1(self.batchnorm(self.linear1(x))))
        y = self.act2(self.linear2(x))

        return y
    
    def save(self):
        torch.save(self.state_dict(), './trainedmodel.pt')

    def load(self):
        self.load_state_dict(torch.load('./trainedmodel.pt', weights_only = True))

Also I have augmentations:
[
    Resize((80, 180)),
    RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    RandomRotation(20),
    RandomAffine(degrees=15, translate=(0.1, 0.1)),
    Grayscale(),

]

I also divide image by 255.
I tried to set dropout probability to 0.5 on linear, 0.2 on conv:

0.5 on linear, 0.5 on conv:

0.8 on linear, 0.8 on conv:

But it always overfits. I'm using Adam(lr=0.001); CrossEntropyLoss. Why does it happen?

Can you post your model code?

Without seeing your code, I could be missing something. However, simple CNNs like the one you posted above, are notoriously difficult to train. It could be possible that you just haven't found the correct hyper parameters. Consider creating a script that runs through many different combinations of learning rates, l2 regularization terms, and dropouts. If that doesn't work, it might be the case that you just need more data.

I have added code of model. When my model was bigger - it wasn't learning. I will try to experiment with hyper parameters, but I think it won't help. Everyone tells me, that I need more data. But how much data is good for my task? Thank you for your answer.

Bigger CNNs should be accompanied with skip connections, which improve gradient flow and smooth the loss surface significantly. Also, generally, if you find yourself backed into a corner after you have rigorously tested your training pipeline, it helps to shift from a build mindset to and understanding one. What is the distribution of image in the train and test set? What are my convolutional layers learning? What does a 2d projection of the output of my final linear layer look like?
